# How to connect points and absorbing momentum?

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm, uibezierpath, shortest-path

I am currently working with a show laser device like [this](http://nicolas.baumgardt.ch/pictures/showlaser.jpg). The device receives a list of 2D points which is then displayed. Internally there's a [galvanometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanometer) that controls the mirror for projecting the laser points.

Let's say I want to display 5 laser points (A, B, C, D, E). Since the laser device doesn't like to travel long distances within short time intervals, one has to add intermediate points, called blanking points (the laser is off while traveling along these blanking points). This procedure is fulfilling the purpose of not stressing the galvanometer too much.

I am currently calculating the "shortest path" in between the 5 points with a simple [Nearest Neighbor algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm), ending up with straight blanking lines (red dotted line in following illustration).

[image]

I achieve already quite good results with this optimization. But I want to go a step further. The galvanometer has some physical momentum when moving. When doing sharp turns, e.g. travelling from C->D and D->E, it does stress the laser device.

So I was thinking about absorbing some of this physical momentum by introducing curved blanking lines instead of straight blanking lines (cp. to last image in above illustration "Solution?").

Any idea how to achieve that?

Pointing to some algorithm resources and/or some pseudo-code or C# would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: As you need it only for the blanking lines, I would look for a simple spline interpolation, e.g. a series of [cubic splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you want to use some kind of cubic spline interpolation for this.

Once you know the time at which each key point will be visited, and the velocity at each point, then you can calculate a piecewise cubic Hermite spline that passes through the key points at the chosen velocities. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline

Since you don't have any particular requirements for the velocities, you probably want to use a classic cubic spline (yes the names for these thing are ambiguous): http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html   This form of spline determines the velocities to ensure that both the first derivative (speed) and second derivative (acceleration) are smoothly varying along the whole path.

Since you also don't have any particular requirements for the exact times at which each key point is reached, you probably want to set the maximum time for the whole path and then choose the timings of the key points to minimize maximum acceleration or something like that.  I don't have a really easy way to do that.  What I would try is:

Initially, make the time between key points proportional to the distance between those points.  Then, apply a few rounds of:

1. Adjust the time spent in each segment to make tangential acceleration 0 at the key points.
2. recalculate the spline

You may be perfectly happy without these optimization rounds, though -- the initial guess is not going to be too bad.

Comment: Thank you very much. I meanwhile implemented the Cubic Hermite Spline approach and it works very well.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the what you are dealing with is a [Traveling-Salesman-Problem(TSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) ([here the slide of a Phd course which talk about how to try to solve it](https://homes.di.unimi.it/cordone/courses/2017-ae/L02.pdf)) and the path that minimze the stress on the laser is the one that minimize the force and the variation of force needed to move it therfore it's the path with the minimum curvature so I think that the best would be to fillet the path between 3 pair of point with an arc of a circle.

An example on how to calculate the parameters of a circle that pass thru 3 points can be found [here](http://www.ambrsoft.com/trigocalc/circle3d.htm)

**I'm not fluent in C# so I'll add a implementation in Python, I hope you find it useful too.**

The idea is that for every triplet of points A,B,C I find the arc of circle that pass for those 3 points and that arc will be the path that connect B and C.

I haden't fot the time to test this yet, so there might be some wrong sign.

```py
# Initial points 
points = [(1,1),(2,3),(5,3),(-4.1),(12,3)]
#List of point in the order find by the solution of the TSP
spl = tsp_solve(points) # generic function to solve the TSP

# Append the first two point of the list so that I can iterate over the list
# and parse every triplet of points in the same way.
spl = spl + spl[:2]

# The list where will be added every path that connect the points
paths = []

# For each tirplets of sequential points
for A,B,C in zip(spl[:-2],spl[1:-1],spl[2:]):
    # Calculate the angular coefficent of the two line that pass on A,B and B,C
    coeff_ab = (B[1] - A[1]) / (B[0] - A[0])
    coeff_bc = (C[1] - B[1]) / (C[0] - B[0])
    # If the two line have the same coeff then all the 3 point are on the same line
    # and therfore the best path is that line.
    if(coeff_ab == coeff_bc):
        offset_y = A[1] - coeff_ab * A[0]   
        delta_x = C[0] - B[0]            
        paths.append({"type":"Line","coeff":coeff_ab,"offset_y":offset_y,"deta_x":delta_x})
        continue
    # Calculate the x of the center of the circle
    center_x  = coeff_ab *coeff_bc *(C[0]-A[0])
    center_x += coeff_ab *(B[0]+C[0]) 
    center_x -= coeff_bc *(A[0]+B[0])
    center_x /= 2*(coeff_ab - coeff_bc)
    # Calculate the y of the center of the circle
    center_y  = (A[1]+B[1)/2
    center_y -= (center_x - (A[0] + B[0])/2)
    center_y /= coeff_bc

    radius = sqrt(center_x**2 + center_y**2)

    paths.append({"type":"Circle","Radius":radius,"center_x":center_x,"center_y":center_y})

# Function To Calculate the X and Y of the lines and circles.

def calculate_circle_x(circle,time):
    """Function that return the x of a circle at a given time"""
    time = time + circle["time_off"]
    return circle["radius"] * cos(2*pi*time) + circle["center_x"]
def calculate_circle_y(circle,time):
    """Function that return the y of a circle at a given time"""
    time = time + circle["time_off"]
    return circle["radius"] * sin(2*pi*time) + circle["center_y"]

def calculate_line_x(line,time):
    """Function that return the x of a line at a given time"""
    time = (line['delta_x']*time) + line["time_off"]
    return time
def calculate_line_y(line,time):
    """Function that return the y of a line at a given time"""
    time = (line['delta_x']*time) + line["time_off"]
    return time * line["coeff"] + line['offset_y']

def calculate_x(obj,time):
    """Function that return the x of whatever it's passed"""
    if(obj['type'] == 'Circle'):
        return calculate_circle_x(obj,time)
    else:
        return calculate_line_x(obj,time)

def calculate_y(obj,time):
    """Function that return the y of whatever it's passed"""
    if(obj['type'] == 'Circle'):
        return calculate_circle_y(obj,time)
    else:
        return calculate_line_y(obj,time)

# Calculate some sample of the global path to plot it or do whatever with it.
number_of_sample = 100000
path_points = []
number_of_paths = len(paths)

# Calculate some time equidistant point's sample
for i in range(number_of_sample):
    # Calculate the global time
    global_time = i*number_of_paths/number_of_sample
    # Calculate in which path the point it is
    path_number = int(global_time)
    # Calculate which time of the path it is
    local_time  = global_time - path_number
    path = paths[path_number]
    # Calculate the sampled point
    new_point = (calculate_x(path,local_time),calculate_y(path,local_time))
    # Add the sampled point to the path_points list
    path_points.append(new_point)

# Print the result of the path point sampled.
print(path_points)
```

Now you have the points or at least the example on how to calculate the points and you can translate it to C#. I tryed to comment it a lot so you might understand it even without knowing Python.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did help me to finalize my project. I gave a thumb up for your answer.